# convert two single bits into a vector

Tags: verilog

I have the following code:

```
module ALUControl(ALUOp, FuncCode, ALUCtl);
input [1:0] ALUOp;
input [5:0] FuncCode;
output reg [3:0] ALUCtl;
always @(ALUOp, FuncCode) begin
    if ( ALUOp == 2 )
        case (FuncCode)
            32: ALUCtl<=2; // add
            34: ALUCtl<=6; //subtract
            36: ALUCtl<=0; // and
            37: ALUCtl<=1; // or
            39: ALUCtl<=12; // nor
            42: ALUCtl<=7; // slt
            default: ALUCtl<=15; // should not happen
        endcase
    else
        case (ALUOp)
            0:  ALUCtl<=2;
            1: ALUCtl<=6;
            default: ALUCtl<=15; // should not happen
        endcase
end
endmodule

module Control(op0 , op1 , op2 , op3 , op4 ,op5  , MemtoReg, RegDst , RegWrite , MemRead , MemWrite ,Branch , ALUSrc, ALUOp1 , ALUOp2 , MemWrite);
    input  op0;
    input  op1;
    input  op2;
    input  op3;
    input  op4;
    input  op5;
    output RegDst;
    output ALUSrc;
    output MemtoReg;
    output MemWrite;
    output MemRead ;
    output RegWrite;
    output Branch;
    output ALUOp1;
    output ALUOp2;

    assign RegDst = (~op0)&(~op1)&(~op2)&(~op3)&(~op4)&(~op5);
    assign ALUSrc = (((op0)&(op1)&(~op2)&(~op3)&(~op4)&(op5))| ((op0)&(op1)&(~op2)&(op3)&(~op4)&(op5)));
    assign MemtoReg = ((op0)&(op1)&(~op2)&(~op3)&(~op4)&(op5));
    assign RegWrite = ((~op0)&(~op1)&(~op2)&(~op3)&(~op4)&(~op5))|((op0)&(op1)&(~op2)&(~op3)&(~op4)&(op5));
    assign MemRead = ((op0)&(op1)&(~op2)&(~op3)&(~op4)&(op5));
    assign MemWrite = ((op0)&(op1)&(~op2)&(op3)&(~op4)&(op5));
    assign Branch = ((~op0)&(~op1)&(op2)&(~op3)&(~op4)&(~op5));
    assign ALUOp1 = ((~op0)&(~op1)&(~op2)&(~op3)&(~op4)&(~op5));
    assign ALUOP2 = ((~op0)&(~op1)&(op2)&(~op3)&(~op4)&(~op5));
endmodule
```

The `Control` module has two outputs, "ALUOp1" and "ALUOp2", and `ALUControl` has an input, "ALUOp", which is a 2-bit vector.  One of the bits of ALUOp is ALUOp1, and the other is ALUOp2.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
output ALUOp1;
output ALUOp2;
```

You want:

```
output [1:0] ALUOp;

wire ALUOp1;
wire ALUOp2;

assign ALUOp = {ALUOp2, ALUOp1};
```

It uses the concatenation operator I mentioned in [my Answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198043/i-cant-understand-the-following-verilog-code/6202135#6202135).